# Phonegap Multiple Push notification,when open one and go back it deletes all my notification from Tray - Android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I get all push notifications which can be seen in tray.But after click on one of the notifications the app is open and the other notifications stay on bar But when you press the home button then the app goes in background and also the tray clears all notifications. But I want the notifications intact

on Clear :
1- App in background 
2- Send Multiple notifications
3- you can see all Notifications 
4- Click on one of theme and the app is opened
5- other Notifications stay in bar when the app is open
6- when you press back button or home button all the notifications removed

i'm using https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem will be solved by removing the two lines that cancels the notifications once the home button is pressed:

```
final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

These two lines are found in the `onPause()` method in `PushPlugin.java` file.

Comment: I tried doing this but still not able to resolve this problem.

Comment: Hello, first just make sure that the cancelAll() method is not called somewhere else